# Bad JSON request using One Drive API

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, api, onedrive

My goal is to create a folder programmatically in OneDrive API using Javascript/Jquery in the application that I'm building.  I am not using Node.js or Angular.js.  I have registered my application with OneDrive's Application Registration Portal, then used the token flow to get the access token from my web browser url address bar.  Now that I have the access token, I'm trying to send it and my request to the API.  Below is my code:

```
var accesshash = window.location.hash.substring(1);
    //console.log(url);
    console.log(accesshash);

    var token = JSON.parse('{' + accesshash.replace(/([^=]+)=([^&]+)&?/g, '"$1":"$2",').slice(0,-1) + '}', function(key, value) { return key === "" ? value : decodeURIComponent(value); });

    console.log(token.access_token);

    var url = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root/children/"
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    if(xhr.readyState == 4) {
        console.log("success");
    }

    xhr.open("POST", url, true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token.access_token);

    var newfolder = {
          "name": "0000000000",
          "folder": {}
        }
    xhr.send(newfolder);
```

I'm getting this as my JSON response:

```
{
  "error": {
"code": "BadRequest",
"message": "Unable to read JSON request payload. Please ensure Content-Type header is set and payload is of valid JSON format.",
"innerError": {
  "request-id": "c8d43cbc-a59b-4244-8c4e-9193295ec7f8",
  "date": "2018-06-07T19:42:57"
 }
}
```

}

Does this mean that my access token is at least valid?  Or is something wrong with it?   Is there something I'm missing?   This is my first time attempting to integrate Onedrive API into an application.

Answer (score 1):

You are sending object, but content type is `application/json`, json is string representation of javascript object

```
xhr.open("POST", url, true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8"); // added charset
xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token.access_token);

var newfolder = {
  "name": "0000000000",
  "folder": {}
}
xhr.send(JSON.stringify(newfolder)); // converted to string
```

There are many http libraries like [fetch](https://github.com/github/fetch), [request](https://github.com/request/request) - that can make your life much easier

Comment: Thanks, I was looking into the Fetch API, but I kept getting the cross origin policy error.   :/   However, now that I've used the JSON.stringify method, the json response is saying that my token is invalid, even though I took it from the web address url.

Comment: `token is invalid` is another case, and might have other possible issues like: wrong token parsing, token access rights, token expiration date, etc...